# Laravel: check if two users are simultaneously logged in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to validate the use of coupons in my app by checking if both the business' owner and the final client are the ones *redeeming* the coupon. This would be the process:

- **Client** shows his QR code
- **Owner** scans it
- **Coupon** is redeemed if both of them are logged in (this would happen when the **Owner**'s device makes a `post` request and uses `CouponController`)

I know I can use `auth()` to validate the owner's status (he wouldn't be able to access the *Redeem* view when logged out anyway), but is there any way to check if the **Client** is also logged in without modifying the `User` row in the database? Right now, I use the following:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
      ...

      public function store()
      {
          if( !auth()->attempt(request(['email','password'])) ){
              return back()->withErrors([
                 'message' => 'Please check your credentials and try again.'
              ]);
          }

          $user = User::find(auth()->id());
          $user->active = 1;
          $user->save();

          return redirect()->home();
      }
```

Comment: Or a completely different way: 1. Client app requests a nonce. 2. Central Service issues a nonce with a short expiry window. 3. Client app includes the nonce in the QR data. [eg: `{"userid": 1, "couponid": 2, "nonce": 3}`] 4. Owner app scans Client QR, sends to Central Service for validation. 5. Request is validated and nonce is invalidated for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first clarify on how **PHP scripts** work and how that impacts your path to know if a user is online or not.

Under your Laravel application, for the very reasons on *how PHP processes HTTP requests*, you can **only** identify *hits* (requests), that you can *interpret* like *heartbeats*. So, you cannot (at least with bare PHP) see the user online all the time, but you can *assume* the user is there if the page hit was **recently**.

That said, it will be up-to-you what will be the **acceptable time window** to interpret if the user is online or not, once given a page hit/http request.

If you only record that the user is active (as a boolean/int flag like `$user->active = 1`) upon login, you will think the user is active **even long after the user is gone** from the application, as the user session may perfectly remain still active (open) but the user is actually inactive.

There are many ways to go around this.

One possible approach is to remember the last time a user hit your page, so you consider him online after the next -say- 5 minutes (this value is up to you). This approach is fair enough for what you are willing to achieve. Keeping this track can be achieved with middlewares, so your controllers are kept clean.

On *how exactly implement this*, well, that would be an entire and opinionated git project to post here and it's probably outside the scope of this answer. Long story short, think of keeping record of **timestamps** of the events you will consider relevant as user activity, instead of a flag with no timing information.

---

If you are willing to implement this as a usable feature with external packages, here are a few options:

- https://github.com/highideas/laravel-users-online
- https://github.com/thomastkim/laravel-online-users
- https://github.com/joshrainwater/active-users

Even if you are not willing to pull in a third party package, feel free to dig in their sources (start on the Traits) to get some ideas on how to go around this.

You will also notice that some of them use **Cache** to keep track of disposable data without the need of storing this into your business ERD in database.

Hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075968/check-if-user-online-laravel