# How to get online users(in real time)

Tags: laravel

I have a task to display a list of online users present on the site. I've been said that I should use web-sockets for this.
I don't know how to implement this. I've already installed Pusher and Laravel Echo. Could you help me by pointing in right direction? I guess I should listen for the moment when user socket connects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if user online laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075968/check-if-user-online-laravel)

Comment: Brad can you please explain a little better your needs? Because if you need to show a "realtime" list of online users (in a chat style) then yes, a websocket is a good way to achieve your goal, otherwise @PrafullaKumarSahu is right and your question is a duplicate

Comment: @IlGala   I've been said to use websockets for this in a chat style. Does it make my question a duplicate?

Comment: @IlGala The question is about can I do this using Pusher and Laraver Echo? Is it a right choice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50076157/2564380

Comment: @Mohammad b   Does it use websockets?

Comment: @Brad_Fresh yes, I was just ensuring that I've understood your needs. Anyway I'll prepare an answer but It's not that simple to summarize

Comment: @IlGala I'll be right here;)

Comment: @IlGala  I've already know how to create an Event and a Listener so there should be no problems with it. I just stuck with what should I listen for?

Comment: Oh, ok... So, I think the "easy way" is to listen for a user login and logout. When this happens you just have to dispatch the relative events to a specific channel available to all users. Then in your frontend you update the "online users" list and it's done

Comment: @IlGala This is what I was looking for- steps to take to accomplish the given task. I think you should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading all the comments I've imagined two possible solutions:

### Broadcast when a user logs in / out

This is the very simple solution. You can use [laravel notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications) that allows you to implement a specific broadcast logic:

- During the login / logout phase create a `UserLogged[In|Out]` notification and broadcast it to a specific channel
- Using [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#receiving-broadcasts) and a "few lines" of javascript, update your `onlineUsers` list (for example in VueJs you may want to update the Vuex store)

But this may require a more complex logic and you may have to write a lot of code to keep the online users list updated... I think it's better to move to solution #2...

### Use [presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels)

I think this is the best way, since it doesn't require nothing else that a good Laravel-echo configuration. For the example I'm using Pusher (since you asked for), but this solution can be implemented with all the Laravel broadcast drivers.

- When a user logs in, simply subscribe him / her to a presence channel ([here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#presence-channels) the Laravel documentation)
- Using Laravel Echo, subscribe the user to that channel

```
var chatRoom = Echo.join('my.chat.room.id');
```

- Once subscribed use the[`members.count`](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#members-count-number-) method to keep an updated list of the channel users.
- Using a `setTimeout()` function you can have a realtime update of the users list.

#### Notes

I've never implemented this solutions in a production environment, but just wrote some code to see how it works. so I think that if other people have diffent point of view or have a better way to explain this process I will be happy to update my answer.