# laravel: how to check the other user is logged in .. like your friend is online

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

laravel: i want to know the solution.. If i logged in my account in my browser and i try to open other browser like incognito... and open other account.. and my problem i want to check or detect the other user is open.... like friend....is online.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if user online laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075968/check-if-user-online-laravel)

Comment: If I really understand your question, then you can check it with IP

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple answers to this question, you can use redis to live check all your currently logged in usersn but I can show you a simpler way :

Add a last_activity column in your use table,

then add a middleware in your app doing this :

```
if(auth()->check()){
  auth()->user()->update(['last_activity' => now()]);
}
```

then assuming you have a friends() many to many relation in your user model

you can do this :

```php
$online_friends = auth()->user()->friends()->where('last_activity' , '>', now()->subMinutes(5))->get();
```