# Check if a specific user is connected | Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, authentication, logout

I would like to know if there is any way to know if a user is currently active (with the session started) on my page.

I know that `Auth::check()` exists but it only returns if the Local user is authenticated, I can't use it to ask for any user.

I have modified the `LoginController` so that, in the login method and in the logout method, the database modifies me and thus know if it has started or has been disconnected.
But this solution becomes useless if the user logs out in another way, for example by closing the browser.

It occurred to me that I could create a kind of setTimeOut event that checks `Auth::check()` every 10 minutes and if it returns false, modify the database of that user understanding that he is no longer connected. But I do not know how to do it.

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if user online laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075968/check-if-user-online-laravel)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the session database so you can check all the  logged in users within your platform and its last activity.

here is the session database schema

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

then adjust your `SESSION_DRIVER=database` then you'll see all the active/inactive session within your session database.

Comment: This definitely answers the question and should be the accepted answer. In addition, Laravel supports additional session drivers which can be used to support something similar, and allows you to define a custom one if needed: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session